# Make a 1 columns per row table into 2 columns per row table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange issue.

I have a table that will show the output as

```
User1
User2
User3
User4

......
```

That will have lot of rows.

Now this is the output of some control

I want to show the data as

```
User1   User3
User2   User4
```

**OR**

```
User1   User2
User3   User4
```

So my table is split to show two columns in-spite of one.

I am trying to use some after method of jquery but no sucess.

There is no header of the table.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

The whole html is a output that was generated by asp.net grid view.

Since grid view supports paging so i go with gridview and then as per the reuirement i want to split it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem using:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {


        for (var i = 0; i <= $('.grid tr').length - 3; i = i + 2) {
            $('.grid tr').eq(i).append($('.grid tr').eq(i + 1).html());
            $('.grid tr').eq(i + 1).hide();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: last row is not coming properly

Comment: @nDudani Actually i dont want to show the last row as that was a pager. This whole html is a output of a asp.net grid view thats why i dont want to show the pager

Comment: What about `$(".grid tr").eq(i + 1).remove().appendTo($(".grid tr").eq(i));`? One line of code which removes odd rows and appends them to the previous row. Also note that this will put 1 & 2, 3 & 4, 5 & 6 next to each other, whereas your original question asks about putting 1 to n / 2 in column 1 and n / 2 + 1 to n in the 2nd column - i.e. using the example of 1-6, 1 and 4 will be next to each other, as will 2 and 5 and 3 and 6.

Comment: I was just about to say what @ClarkeyBoy did - this doesn't produce the output that the question asked for, where the sample output showed that the bottom half of the table had been moved up next to the top half (which is what I did with my answer).

Comment: That's a much simpler way of saying what I just said... I never think of simple ways to put things lol

Answer (score 7):

Something like the following will work:

```
var $tds = $("#yourtable td"),
    i, j;

for (i=0, j=Math.ceil($tds.length / 2); j < $tds.length; i++,j++)
   $($tds[i]).parent().append($tds[j]);
```

As shown in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fx7jR/).

Note, the `Math.ceil()` bit is to allow for an odd number of rows (also shown in my demo).

(Obviously the above only works if the table has only one column to start with.)

Answer (score 3):

Very Basic Code, work for user defined #td, you just need to change value of nCol.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Nimit Table two colonm</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myNewTable='<table><tr>';
    var itemCounter=1;
    var nCol=2;
    $('#myTable td').each(function(index) {
        if( (itemCounter%nCol)==0)
            myNewTable = myNewTable + '<td>'+$(this).html()+'</td></tr><tr>';
        else
            myNewTable = myNewTable + '<td>'+$(this).html()+'</td>';

        itemCounter++;
    });
    myNewTable=myNewTable+'</tr></table>';
    $('#myTable').html(myNewTable);

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
    <tr><td>Item1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item10</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't this move "Item2" up next to "Item1", "Item4" up next to "Item3" and so forth? Because that's not what the question asked for...

Answer (score 0):

**Not Tested**, but you could do something like following:

```
$(".your_table_class > tbody > tr").each(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).addClass("column01"),
    $tds = $tr.children(), 
    midSection = Math.floor($tds.length / 2), 
    $newColumn = $('<tr />', {class: "column02"}).insertAfter($tr);
    $tds.each(function(j) {
      j > midSection && $(this).appendTo($newColumn); 
    });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I have also posting my answer can you please have a look to improve it as that was working or you can modifiy and update your answer. Thank you