# CSS table with variable number of columns to fit to screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, css-tables

Basically the same question as "[Creating a html table with dynamically expanding number of columns to fit screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238501/creating-a-html-table-with-dynamically-expanding-number-of-columns-to-fit-screen)".

However, I'm looking for a pure Javascript solution without third party libraries. I don't have access to them.

The starting point is as follows:

```
<div id="icons"></div>

#icons {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.iconBody { display: table-row-group; } /* May not be necessary to solution */
.iconRow { display: table-row; }
.iconCell { display: table-cell; }

function loadValues() {
  // other stuff
  var iconTable = document.getElementById("icons");

  // TODO following lines are editable to suit the solution as necessary
  for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; ++i) {
    addIcon(iconTable, icons[i]);
  }
}

function addIcon(iconTable,  icon)  {
  // TODO add solution here

  // Row addition example
  var row = document.createElement("DIV");
  row.className = "iconRow";
  iconTable.appendChild(row);

  // Cell addition example
  var cell = document.createElement("DIV");
  cell.className = "iconCell";
  row.appendChild(cell);

  // Icon addition example
  var iconImg = document.createElement("IMG");
  var iconImg.src = icon.srcPath;
  iconImg.addEventListener("click", someFunction);
  cell.appendChild(iconImg) ;
}
```

This table has no headers/labels, just an array of icons for the user to select one from. The icons are of the same dimensions with each other, though the icons are stored server-side so I may or may not be able to obtain their dimensional values. These values will never change though. The application panel from which the page is displayed can be resized, so I want the number of columns this table has to fit according to the panel's current width without horizontal overflow.

The application uses IE 11.212.10586.0 to display web pages.

Answer (score 1):

The following Snippet generates a table of images derived from an array. It will generate additional columns to ensure that the table is edge to edge in viewport. Details are commented in source. Use <kbd>Expand snippet</kbd> button to see it function. It doesn't change columns on a resize, just at load.

#### SNIPPET

```
Usage:
 iconGrid(rows);
 rows = integer representing the amount of rows desired by user or developer.
```

```js
/*[iconGrid]~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/

// Array of image url fragment from server
var icos = ['00e/fc0?text=I1.png', '000/fff?text=I2.png', 'e00/000?text=I3.png', '0e0/fff?text=I4.png', 'e0e/000?text=I5.png'];

// Reference the table
var icons = document.getElementById('icons');

// Create a documentFragment - faster to append to
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

// Declare increment vars outside of loop
var i;
var j;

/*
| genIcons(number of rows, number of columns)
|
| First loop creates a row and appends it to frag
|
| Second loop creates img and cells equal to the
| amount of columns designated by the second parameter
|
| Upon each iteration rows are given .row class and 
| cells are given .cel class. Each row and cell gets an
| id as well
|
| Each img is given a base url that points to the 
| location of the image files. The actual filename is 
| determined from the icos[] array from the server.
|
| Last step the frag is appended to #icons. 
*/
function genIcons(x, y) {
  var rows = parseInt(x, 10);
  var cels = parseInt(y, 10);
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement('section');
    row.id = 'r' + i;
    row.className = 'row';
    frag.appendChild(row);
    for (j = 0; j < cels; j++) {
      var ico = document.createElement('img');
      var cel = document.createElement('div');
      ico.src = 'http://placehold.it/50x50/' + icos[j];
      cel.appendChild(ico);
      cel.id = 'c' + i + j;
      cel.className = 'cel';
      row.appendChild(cel);
    }
  }
  icons.appendChild(frag);
}

/*
| iconGrid(number of rows)
|
| vpWidth is the viewport width in px. This
| measures the width of visible area of the 
| browser's window in somecases like an iframe such 
| as the one on the right is the viewport.
|
| The number of columns needed is determined by the
| viewport width divided by 50 (the set width of a cell)
|
| Finally, genIcons() creates the grid with the number
| of rows determined by you and the number of columns 
| determined by viewport width. Note: there are 5 colors in
| in the icos[] array the white cells were made to fill
| width.
*/
function iconGrid(rows) {
  var vpWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var columns = Math.floor(vpWidth / 50);
  genIcons(rows, columns);
}

iconGrid(5);
```

```css
#icons {
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  min-width: 50px;
  width: 99vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
section {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-row;
}
section > div {
  width: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main id="icons"></main>
```